# Button `disabled` vs `[disabled]="true"`

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the `material.io` examples for the `button` tag, I see this:-

```
<button mat-button disabled>Disabled</button>
```

The use of the `disabled` attribute instead of `[disabled]="true"` is not documented anywhere. Also, whilst it is obvious the use of the `disabled` attribute declares the initial state of the button to be disabled, there is no example of how to enable such a button after the initial state is set.

How do you enable a button declared with `<button mat-button disabled>` at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this [Angular Property Binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding)

Comment: I was aware of what that link is saying, I'm really inquiring about the use of attribute `disabled` without any binding or assigning a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

`<button mat-button disabled>` is just an example to illustrate the disabled `MatButton`.

In order to achieve toggle behavior of disabled state, it's better to make use of Angular `property binding` syntax.

Coming to the below point, if one really has to disable the button by simply using the `disabled` attribute, and then toggle it later: This can be achieved by getting hold of the `button` reference within Component `ts` file and manually setting or removing the `disabled` attribute within the Component method. We can achieve this with `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute` methods.

> How do you enable a button declared with <button mat-button disabled> at runtime?